# Match first matching hierarchical descendant with jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**[edit]** I have reworded the question and removed the example, since it seems to confuse you. Sorry for trouble.

I need to match the first descendant which match a selector.

If multiple elements match this selector but are in separates trees (i.e. if one is not the parent of another) then I want to select both of them.

The exact DOM structure is not known, so I can't use functions like `.children( )` or the `>` selector (because they expect the user to be sure about the actual DOM structure).

What I need actually look like the `.closest( )` function, but for matching children instead of parents, and potentially multiple children at once.

Comment: If you can guarantee unique IDs, surely `$('#B').find('#C')` would work?

Comment: @BoltClock. But hr wrote he couldn't, and I thought you're jQuery and css master, why do you need `find` for `id` selector?!

Comment: @gdoron: I'm just basing this on his `.find('...')` example. He also didn't say that `#B` and `#C` *don't* exist in the real code, so I'm assuming that they do exist, and throwing something at him. Ideally yes you would be able to just use `$('#C')`... but I guess I don't really understand what is happening in the OP's actual code.

Comment: idk why you want to do something like you can just select by `$("#C")`?

Comment: @BoltClock "they don't exists in the real architecture". This code is template-generated at multiple places, I can't (and don't want to) put IDs everywhere.

Comment: The only allowed ID in the solution is #B, because it actually represents a jQuery object that I already know (it is stored in a variable).

Comment: @BoltClock. I was only teasing you... :) Anyway I deleted my answer as this question seems to be too vague and too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every tree starting from `#B` is defined by `.children()`; every first `.foo` within such a tree is `.find('.foo:eq(0)')`, so you should be able to use this:

```
$('#B').children(':not(.foo)').andSelf().find('.foo:eq(0)');
```

Comment: There is a single `.foo` in my own code, but I'm wondering if there is a way to match every `.foo` first-child, like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7gfFP/2/) example (CCC and GGG should be highlighted).

Comment: Your new solution (`$('#B').children().find('.foo:eq(0)');`) is working (the other does not, because the child selector prevent multiple imbrication level). However, I'm not sure to understand why `.find('.foo:eq(0)')` is not returning the same thing that `.find('.foo').eq(0)`.

Comment: Ok, I get it, actually it is not working (but it's almost that!). It can't match first-child `.foo`s (in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7gfFP/4/), BBB should be highlighted too).

Comment: @MaëlNison No offense, but I think you have to get your mind sorted on what exactly you need :)

Comment: I need to match the first descendant which match a selector. If multiple elements match this selector but are in separates trees (i.e. if one is not the parent of another) then I want to select both of them. The exact DOM structure is not known, so I can't use functions like `.children( )` or the `>` selector (because they expect the user to be sure about the actual DOM structure).

Comment: Almost, there is a single issue if one of the top-child is `.foo` and if it contains another `.foo` ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/7gfFP/5/), CCC shouldn't be highlighted)

Comment: note `addSelf` is deprecated. you can replace it with `addBack`, but I also think the expression could be optimized by using `addBack` with a selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery Plugin [closestDescendant](http://plugins.jquery.com/closestDescendant/)

That implemenst a breadth first search, so its checks all children of current element befor it goes down to the next level.

after loading plugin or adding it to you source code you could simple call it in this way:

```
jQuery('#parent').closestDescendant(".selector", true)
```

Here you can find a demo of that function: [demo closestDescendant](http://tlindig.github.io/jquery-closest-descendant/)